# How to recover password of Hotmail

Tags: outlook.com, account-recovery

Could you please advise me on how to recover a password for my Hotmail account which I have forgotten as I have not used this address for years?

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to login via Windows 10 with Chrome there is a small option underneath the part where you would normally enter your password, which says: `Forgot my password` in blue writing.  It may be difficult to see, but it's showing up for me at any rate.